# How to create new JavaScript snippet for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, snippets

I want `c` to trigger `console.log()`

The snippet I created has the correct syntax below and is in the correct folder paths according to these articles: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-code-snippets/ | http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html

[image]

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
console.log(${1:this});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>c</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.JavaScript</scope>
</snippet>
```

I have the snippet file created inside of my `User` folder, as well a `User/Javascript` folder. It has the correct `sublime-snippet` extension as well.

Went through the trouble of installing the JavaScript default snippets, but now instead of just `console` it does `console.dir(obj)` who uses that lol? Anyways if I can't create my own custom snippets, how can I edit this one?

Comment: The scope should be `source.javascript`. The `J` and the `S` are not capitalized.

Comment: I tried that as well, did not work :( I finally got it to work when I removed the `<scope>` line though, however now `c` will work in all scopes.

Comment: Nevermind, I just checked - it's `source.js`. My bad.

Comment: Ah thanks! That was it, want to post the answer? @MattDMo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base scope for JavaScript files in Sublime is `source.js`, not `source.javascript`. You can find the complete scope at the cursor by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Linux/Windows) or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (OS X).